# Can I query posts by taxonomy conditionally based on post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, query

I have a query based on multiple post_types and taxonomies that works well, however I would like to add a level of complexity and query a taxonomy only for a specific taxonomy.

This query works as expected:

```
Array
(
    [topic] => global-reach
    [sections] => programs-and-services
    [regions] => ghana
    [post_type] => Array
        (
            [0] => publications
            [1] => media_releases
            [2] => page
        )
    [posts_per_page] => 10
)
```

Now I would like to select only the 'pages' that have the taxonomy 'options' set to 'set-as-news-item' ... here is a somewhat unlogical pseudo query of what I would like to accomplish, but it should get the idea across.

```
Array
(
    [topic] => global-reach
    [sections] => programs-and-services
    [regions] => ghana
    [post_type] => Array
        (
            [0] => aucc_publication
            [1] => aucc_media
            [2] => Array 
                     (
                       [post_type] => 'page',
                       [options] => 'set-as-news-item'
                     (
        )
    [posts_per_page] => 10
)
```

I could use the first query above and filter out unwanted posts as I loop them, but then I could not use Wordpress' built-in pagination.

I'm asking for too much out of WP_Query right?

Comment: You can't query pages with a specific term but other types without it, not within the same query, the query class just can't do queries with that level of complexity.. (at least not at the moment)..

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Is my only option to resort to direct SQL queries?

Answer (score 2):

As t31os said, you can't do that using WP_Query directy.

You can attempt to use the 'posts_clauses' filter to modify the individual SQL clauses generated by WP_Query, but it will be quite tricky, however you do it.

Instead, it might be easier to replace the entire SQL query. You can use get_tax_sql() to take care of the taxonomy part (not tested):

```
function my_posts_request( $old_query, $wp_query ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $ptypes = $wp_query->get('post_type');

    if ( 'page' != $ptypes[2]['post_type'] )
      return $old_query; // This is not the WP_Query you are looking for

    // Do the conditional tax_query
    $tax_query = array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'options',
        'terms' => array( 'set-as-news-item' ),
        'field' => 'slug',
      )
    );

    $clauses = get_tax_sql( $tax_query, $wpdb->posts, 'ID' );

    $join = "FROM $wpdb->posts {$clauses['join']}";
    $where = "WHERE (
      post_type = 'aucc_publication' OR 
      post_type = 'aucc_media' OR 
      (post_type = 'page' {$clauses['where']})
    )";

    // Do the other tax query
    $tax_query = array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'section',
        'terms' => array( 'programs-and-services' ),
        'field' => 'slug',
      ),
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'regions',
        'terms' => array( 'ghana' ),
        'field' => 'slug',
      )
    );

    $clauses = get_tax_sql( $tax_query, $wpdb->posts, 'ID' );

    $join .= $clauses['join'];
    $where .= $clauses['where'];

    return "SELECT $wpdb->posts.* $join $where ORDER BY post_date LIMIT 10";
}
add_filter( 'posts_request', 'my_posts_request' );
```

You'll still have to take care of pagination etc. Take a look at how WP_Query does it.

Comment: **"This is not the WP_Query you are looking for"** - Your jedi mind tricks won't work on me young padawan!... +1 just for the Jedi reference(even if i'm the only one that noticed)...

Comment: Thanks-  I have yet to give this a try ... will post results later on